# Issue when sending a large array of objects via ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, .htaccess

I have an array of over 1000 objects, and I want to send it via ajax to a php file:

```
 var storiesToSave = Stories.sort(function(a,b){
                return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date);
            });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "saveStories.php",
            data: {"stories": JSON.stringify(storiesToSave)},
            success: function (result) {alert(result);},
            error: function(request, status, error) {alert("Error: Could not save because "+ error); }
        });
```

Now I've tried all this locally using a XAMPP server and it works fine, but when I tried to upload it to the website (I'm using a free hosting service - 000webhost) it doesn't work.

I do not get errors, but the $_POST remains empty.  Every once in a while it seems to randomly work, but 99% of the time it is empty.  I have tried splicing the first 20 objects in the array, and then it works, but as I increase the numbers, it starts failing more.

I have tried a couple of solutions from Stack Overflow, but they all seem to yield similar results.

Without the json conversion:

```
jQuery.post("saveStories.php", {stories: storiesToSave}, function(data){ alert(data); });
```

And this one doesn't even work on the XAMPP server (using the content type json):

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "saveStories.php",
            data: JSON.stringify({"stories": storiesToSave}),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (result) {alert(result);},
            error: function(request, status, error) {alert("Error: Could not save because "+ error); }
        });
```

and as a last resort i have also added these lines to my .htaccess file, but they don't seem to affect anything

```
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M

php_value max_input_vars 100000
```

So overall the issue seems to be with the large size (which is still only a few bytes), and only on the server (hopefully not a limitation of the free hosting service).  Is there any way to get around this, by changing it or using an entirely different method?

Thanks.

Comment: your web server might also have limits on the max upload size..with a free service...that might be an uphill battle...what about splitting your array into smaller posts?

Comment: Might be what @Ctznkane525 meant: Search the php.ini on your webserver for limitations.

Comment: I have thought of that, but I suppose it would make the algorithm a lot more complicated.  Since I want to save an ordered list, I don't know if it will remain ordered when multiple requests received and saved at the same time.  I also have an issue that I don't know exactly how small the requests have to be.  Sometimes they work, sometimes they don't.

Comment: pass an extra number that indicates the first index of the specific set of content?